# Retaining double quotation marks in biblatex-chicago with British localization

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, chicago-style

I am using `biblatex-chicago`, current version (0.9.9b), with `biber`. I am loading `babel`  with the `british` option in order to get the punctuation right (I need logical quoting). However, this also changes the style of the outer quotation marks from double to single, which is not what I want.

I tried loading babel with `english` and switching autopunct off by setting it to false, but this does not solve my problem.

Is there a way of retaining double quotation marks in in-text references and the bibliography, and still set the main language to `british`?

Comment: Can you post a small example of what you're doing? With a simple test document I get double quotes for both language options for e.g. article titles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How are you dealing with `csquotes` and `biblatex-chicago`?  This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{smith3000,
  author =   {Smith, John},
  title =    {Some Article Title for a Journal},
  journal =  {Journal of Tests},
  date =     2000,
  volume =   33,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {100--150}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[strict=true, style=american]{csquotes}%

\usepackage[%
  english, 
    % either:
  % american% <-- compile twice if you switch
    % or:
  british
  ]{babel}%

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}% 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}%

\begin{document}
The current language is: \languagename.

\cite{smith3000}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I switch the call to `babel`, and compile twice, I get the 'illogical' punctuation (North) Americans favour.

And from `\listfiles`:

```
biblatex-chicago.sty    2012/12/06 v 2.4 biblatex style  
biblatex.sty    2012/12/01 v2.4 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)  
biblatex2.sty    2012/12/01 v2.4 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
[...] 
chicago-notes.bbx    2012/12/06 v 2.4 biblatex bibliography style     
chicago-notes.cbx    2012/12/06 v 2.4 biblatex citationstyle          
biblatex.cfg 
english.lbx    2012/12/01 v2.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
british.lbx    2012/12/01 v2.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
cms-british.lbx    2011/09/28 v 1.6 biblatex localization
```

Comment: Using `\usepackage[british]{babel}` with `\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}` and `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}` does the trick for me. Before I had csquotes load with `babel`, which of course resulted in single quotes. Thank you!

Comment: @icetea275 -- Glad it worked!