# Using csquotes and babel with option "british" reverses order of single and double quotes

Tags: babel, csquotes

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel} % <-- problematic line
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{outside \enquote{inside} outside again}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have double quotes around the outer part and single quotes around the inner part. Generally this works, but adding the marked line changes the roles of single and double quotes.

I'm using pdflatex under Ubuntu.

There was a similar question: [Retaining double quotation marks in biblatex-chicago with British localization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87575/retaining-double-quotation-marks-in-biblatex-chicago-with-british-localization) But I couldn't extract an answer to my case.

Comment: `\usepackage[strict=true, style=american]{csquotes}` from that answer works fine here.

Comment: As far as I know, the most common British style is to have outer single quotes and inner double quotes.

Comment: You may define you own house style. Have a look in the manual.

Comment: @egreg : I will check again how it shall be done.